# "Do UEFI specifications completely replace the BIOS?"

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, post

> Do UEFI specifications completely replace the BIOS? (From uefi.org/faq)
>
> The UEFI specifications define an interface and the BIOS refers to a
>   specific implementation of the firmware that initializes the platform
>   and loads an OS setup. UEFI specifications define an interface in
>   which the implementation of UEFI performs the equivalent of the BIOS,
>   by initiating the platform and loading the operating system.

This is what I found in the official uefi.org website but I'm really not able to understand the answer.

[On the net I found](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2392944,00.asp):

> UEFI does not completely replace the BIOS. UEFI uses a separate interface for boot services and runtime services, but does not specify how the Power-On Self Test (POST) and Setup are implemented. Some platform firmware must still perform these crucial functions, however. Because UEFI is an interface (as its name suggests), it may be implemented "on top" of a traditional BIOS (or, for that matter, a non-BIOS system).

And I didn't find an example of platform that do not perform a POST (or at least I don't know how to search for it)

1. There are system that exclusively have UEFI?
2. Is it sufficient the UEFI high level hardware check?
3. If UEFI is on top of BIOS where is the exact point when one ends and the other starts? How?

UPDATE:
[Read the always excellent ArchLinux documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_boot_process#Under_UEFI)

Comment: A motherboard will either have an iOS or UEFI firmware not both;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a motherboard, hardisk, SSD etc powers up it runs its firmware. For PC style motherboards there are three common firmwares:

1. BIOS.
2. UEFI.
3. CoreBoot.

Each of these is standalone. Neither runs on top of anything else.

So to answer:

> There are system that exclusively have UEFI?

Yes, almost any modern system

> If UEFI is on top of BIOS where is the exact point when one ends and
> the other starts? How?

It is not on top off. The motherboard either starts on **or** do other. There is no handoff.

I suspect that these two questions partially originate to articles which are plainly wrong. E.g. many post say "UEFI BIOS". Which is plain wrong.

Another potential point of confusing is that many UEFI implementations ship with a compatability module (CMS) which emulates the same functionality as BIOS firmware used to offer. But it still is a different product.

That leaves one question which I do not understand:

> Is it sufficient the UEFI high level hardware check?

Comment: the question arises because, from that article, I don't understand if UEFI is able to run a POST. Are there any platforms that don't need to run a POST?

Comment: UEFI is the part which runs POST. It does not run after post. Motherboard gets power. Power stable. CPU starts executing from a predetermined position (which vaires per CPU brand and possibly per model. It runs the code which it finds there (the firmware code) and executes that code. Part of that code is a full POST for BIOS firmware, very limited initialisation for CoreOS firmware and quick or longer init for EFI formware (based on some settings). Regardless, all three check for quite a few standard things while starting. POST (Power On Self Test) is part of that.

Comment: You probably meant to write Coreboot. CoreOS is a Linux distro.

Comment: uhm, yes. Late in the evening and years since I listened to any coreboot presentation. Will correct